# Titanium global color variable

Tags: xml, colors, titanium

i'm new to titanium, and i was wondering if it is possible to define a color in the string.xml which is accessible from the app.tss? I know that it is in native adroid.

```
<resources>
    <string name="txt_loading_meta_data">Lade Metadaten</string>
    <string name="txt_loading_get_appointment">Lade MyDay</string>
```

Thx in advance :

Comment: not sure about string.xml but you may try to define them in alloy.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the color in the Ti.App namespace (global to the application), you can reference that in app.tss files.

The side effect is that you can reference that in views (xml files) and controllers (JS code)

Example app.tss

```
"Window": {
     backgroundColor: Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.WINDOW_BACKGROUND
 }
```

Example alloy.js

```
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR = {};
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.SELECTED_ELEMENT = "#6c9093";
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.WINDOW_BACKGROUND = "#8ab94c";
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.SHADOW = "#305460";
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.RED = "#912323";
Ti.App.STYLE.COLOR.GOLD = "#eee123";
```

Comment: I tried this 100 times and it doesn't seem to work. I'm doing just what you're doing in the example. It doesn't seem to let me set a property such as "WINDOW_BACKGROUND". When I do Ti.API.info() and JSON stringify the COLOR, i get {}. Does this approach no longer work with appcelerator updates or an I doing something wrong?

Comment: I just solved my own problem. The color properties must be set before setting the color object. Here is my example: 'Ti.App.STYLE = {COLOR: {WINDOW_BACKGROUND: "#2C5234"}};'